# process.waitFor() not returning

Tags: java, postgresql, exec

I would like to migrate data from a Postgres SQL script.
I am using the code below.

```java
void importDatabase() {

        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("psql -f ./test.sql postgresql://postgres:root@127.0.0.1:5432/testdb");

        //Wait to get exit value
        try {
            if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.error(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

`waitFor` is not returning anything, it just waits forever.

**Note:** My `test.sql` has many queries so it will display many log entries.

Question:

1. How to solve this problem?
2. If this relates to the buffer memory, how do I clear the buffer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a process executed by `Runtime.exec()` produces output -- either to `stdout` or `stderr` -- then for it to operate robustly you need to start consuming the output before calling `Process.waitFor()`. Most likely, your `psql` process is blocked because it's waiting for something to read its output, and you don't start to do that until `Process.waitFor()` is complete.

You probably need to consume the output in a separate thread, unless you know exactly what output is expected. In any case, there may, or may not, be a problem with your invocation of `psql` -- unless you capture its output you probably won't know.

Robust and portable use of `Runtime.exec()` is surprisingly difficult. I've written about this at length, with code samples, here:

http://kevinboone.me/exec.html